# Explain simple R operation here of reduce. I cannot find any info on the 'c' part of reduce

Tags: r

```
all.words <- reduce(df_all['Words.List'], c)
tokenizer <- text_tokenizer()
tokenizer$fit_on_texts(all.words)
```

Can someone please explain what the 'c' is doing in reduce? It is part of the code of the below notebook.
https://www.kaggle.com/guidant/mimicking-star-wars-characters-using-a-i-rnn/notebook

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the concatenation function so its saying to concatenate all the words in df_all['Words.List']